# React + Meteor filestorage

Tags: mongodb, reactjs, meteor, dropzone.js, gridfs

I am struggling to understand the best data structures with mongo in regards to images/videos/media. Can someone please clarify?

Typically I would store my data in a collection object, for example a blogpost which would have

```
{
title: 'foo',
author: 'john',
created_at: Friday Oct 4,
cover_photo: ???????? (base-64?)
...
}
```

My inclination is to add a "cover_photo" in with this collection. Is this is right approach? I'm sure I could figure out how to base64 encode a huge string and save it here, but my hunch is that is probably not the best way to go about this.

Should I create a second collection `Images` and map ID's somehow? What is the best approach with mongoDB + Meteor?

I am a front-ender trying to get my feet off the ground with Mongo + FS, any help is much appreciated!

I really like Dropzone, but I'm not sure how they can work together. Should I call the `insert` Meteor-method just as I would for another Meteor.call? Or is there more to it on the server-side and this is a special case?

I am able to see the blob, however once refreshed, it is no longer there.

Comment: NoSQL is typically about absence of relations, therefore keeping all the things in one document would be better, since you still query this data to show in the app. What could be the solution, instead, is to upload images to a separate (remote) file storage (think AWS S3) and only store links to files as part of each document in the collection.

Comment: Ah yes, I like this approach a lot! Then I will only have to hit URLs from the client-side and store the refs as strings.